# How can I add categories to homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I want to add some of my categories on homepage, not all but three or four of them by category id. I read something that I have to create a list.phtml and add this as follows to my homepage cms content:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/list.phtml"}}
```

But I am using a custom theme and in this theme exists a mdl-banner.phtml file (path: customtheme/template/catalog/product) which displays a slider on homepage. This file looks as follows:

```
<?php 
    $config = Mage::getStoreConfig( 'bannerslider/homepage' );
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="submenu span3">
        <!-- categories -->
    </div>
    <div class="slide span9 f-fix">
        <div class="container">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bannerslider/default')->setTemplate('mdl/bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml')->setBannersliderId(1)->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I just want to add some categories there where the comment  is.

So I changed this file as follows:

```
<?php 
    $config = Mage::getStoreConfig( 'bannerslider/homepage' );
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="submenu span3">
        <?php $specialCategoryIds = array( '5', '6', '7' ); ?>
        <?php foreach ( $this->getStoreCategories() as $category ): ?>
            <?php $categoryId = $category->getId(); ?>
            <?php if ( !in_array( $categoryId, $specialCategoryIds ) ) continue; ?>
                <?php $open = $this->isCategoryActive( $category ); ?>
                <?php if ( $open ): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl( $category )?>">
                        <?php echo $category->getName(); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="slide span9 f-fix">
        <div class="container">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bannerslider/default')->setTemplate('mdl/bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml')->setBannersliderId(1)->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But now I am getting a blank screen on homepage, because I think I have to say magento that categories are enabled for my homepage, but I don't know where I have to do this because I didn't used a list.phtml? Hope you understand my problem and can help me :)

EDIT:

I changed this file again to:

```
<?php 
    $config = Mage::getStoreConfig( 'bannerslider/homepage' );
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="submenu span3">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/navigation')->setTemplate('catalog/category/list.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="slide span9 f-fix">
        <div class="container">
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bannerslider/default')->setTemplate('mdl/bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml')->setBannersliderId(1)->toHtml(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and its working now for me, but is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be, to create a custom widget, where you can select the corresponding categories you want to show and just use this widget at the cms page or template

Comment: Ok thank you, but I am just a magento beginner. If I want to create a custom widget then I have to proceed like building an extension?

Comment: Thats right, but there are pretty good tutorials out there, even from magento like: [Widget Tutorial Part 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-1)

Comment: Ok thanks again, I have some much to learn :)

Comment: No problem, everyone needs to start :)